# How did android app made to run only on 1 device at a time?

Tags: android

How to make a game run on multiple device at same time? I downloaded a game from play store and want to play it on same time on 2 device but when i play on second device. The first device get error message "sorry, Your account is currently used on another device" but weird thing is that on some device i am able to run the same game at same time with no error.
So my question is how does android app determine weather game is being played on more than 1 device? 
Why sometime its work on more than 1 device but not always?
I have created multiple memu emulator and i am able to run game on more than 1 device on some of them. But it does not work always. 
I try cloning device id but it does not help. So is it something server side thing that detemine weather another device is used at the same time to play game?
Game name : War robots
Connected with google games play for progress save

Thanks

Comment: notice the error msg ""sorry, Your account is currently used on another device". If you are logged in with same account in two devices, thats where it causes the error. Got it..?

Comment: I know but i do not get this error message with every device.Why? I want to know how does app know that i am playing game on 2 device at same time? Is it server side thing? Then why it does not work every time with every device? What stats server check? IMEI, Android version, Device ID, What?

Comment: The error did not come in other device because you may have not logged in with same account. I dont think it checks IMEI,Android version, Device Id. It seems like a server check. It just checks for user id and checks if the usr already logged in on other device.

Comment: thanks for your effort sandeep, Lets see if any developer interested to answer my noobish question.